# How to Convert JSON to XML in java whilst keeping same order of XML attributes as in JSON

Tags: java, json, xml, spring-boot

I have the below function

```
    public String convertToXml(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        String xml = XML.toString(jsonObject);
        return xml;
    }
```

that is converting JSON String to XML. However, some attributes are being swapped from their position for example

```
{"isbn": "123-456-222",  
 "author": 
    {
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "firstname": "Jane"
    },
"editor": 
    {
      "lastname": "Smith",
      "firstname": "Jane"
    },
  "title": "The Ultimate Database Study Guide",  
  "category": ["Non-Fiction", "Technology"]
 }
```

becomes

```
<editor>
    <firstname>Jane</firstname>
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>
</editor>
<author>
    <firstname>Jane</firstname>
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>
</author>
<isbn>123-456-222</isbn>
<title>The Ultimate Database Study Guide</title>
<category>Non-Fiction</category>
<category>Technology</category>
```

How can I make sure that the XML has the same order as JSON? I used *org.json.XML* from

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20210307</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Why does it need to have the same order?  Both XML and JSON typically should not care about order

Comment: The endpoint I am consuming needs it to be inorder

Comment: Please specify the JSON and XML libraries involved in the question.

Comment: I used **org.json**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the Official [JSON-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) repository and changed  `\src\main\java\org\json\JSONObject.java` constructor from

```
public JSONObject() {
        this.map = new HashMap();
    }
```

to

```
public JSONObject() {
        this.map = new LinkedHashMap();
    }
```

then i compiled it again to *.jar* file and include it to my project.